# How to have a common y-label between two subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[image]

In the figure above, there are two `subgraphs`. There are also two subgraphs in each subgraph. But it can be found that the two graphs in each subgraph share a ylabel. So they should be the same graph, using two coordinate axes. `fig.add_axes` can add an axis, but how to add it to the subplot after `subplot()`? Can anyone give some suggestions? Thank you!

I want to use the matplotlib library in python to draw.

Comment: Hard to understand without sample code and data.

Comment: The data is not important, I just want to know how to split the graph into subgraphs like this.  Each of the above subgraphs has two independent coordinate axes and uses the same ylabel. How is this done?

Comment: This is a picture from the paper. I want to draw a similar graph. I have no source code.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

Comment: oh,my God. I know subplot comand. But my question is how does the subgraph  built by the subplot command have two separate axes like the above figure?

Comment: Make it 8 subplots that you [control with gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-gridspec-py).